# bq Aquaris E4.5 cannot handle Mobile Data with Dual SIMs when one is Roaming and Roaming Data switched off

Tags: phone, mobile-broadband, smartphone

Basically the title describes it all
OS Ubuntu 14.10 (r20)
Mobile Data works when only using the local SIM
I have one local SIM and one from another country

I would have expected Mobile Data to work for the SIM which is not Roaming

Comment: This sounds like a bug, so you should report it in Launchpad so that developers can track it there. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers for details - maybe against the ofono package? See also http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html - it would help you described your problem in more detail so that a developer can work on it. Which SIMs are you using? What are you doing in the interface that confirms to you that mobile data isn't working?